# How to increase sensitivity of Capacitive Touch Switch?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am working with `Capacitive Touch Sense` technology.In that I am using `TTP224` Touch detector IC. I am getting good sensitivity when I am using Touch pad without putting any non electric material over it and able to switch ON/OFF connected led.But when I put any non electric material like `Acrylic Sheet` of `2mm` thickness I am not able to get any signal through pad or not able to ON/OFF connected led.

So, How can I increase sensitivity of Touch pad?

[I have bought TTP224 module from here.](http://www.ebay.in/itm/172493711487?aff_source=Sok-Goog)

And what can be the alternatives for `TTP224`???

Comment: Try a different material. Also try to minimize any gap between the pad and the acrylic. Otherwise exchange the capacitors on the board.

Comment: @Gerben...Thanks. There is no gap between pad and acrylic. And yes I am trying with different capacitor values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the datasheet](http://www.tontek.com.tw/download.asp?sn=373) (if you can name it that):

> The capacitance Cs0~Cs3 can be used to adjust the sensitivity. The value of Cs0~Cs3 use smaller, then the sensitivity will be better. The sensitivity adjustment must according to the practical application on PCB. The range of Cs0~Cs3 value are 0~50pF.

So, reduce the capacitances Cs0 to Cs3 and you will get better sensitivity.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes things just ****. In my case, where 0.5 mm more of gap make the TTP223 unable to work, because I designed such a small pad. My solution? Remove the paint in the PCB, put a lot of solder in to make the pad taller. Work like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

remove all c3 to c10 capacitors of 22pf. This will increase sensitivity and will sense through 5 mm sheet also .